# How to make author ping in ctx.respond() discord py

Tags: discord, discord.py

```py
await ctx.respond(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

I want to make author ping without mention like on the screenshot
[image: the screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to change your .respond into a .reply, and add a mention_author=False into your parenthesis.

```py
await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

Comment: I use **py-cord** tools for some functions, this is a cause why I have not reply function, only `respond()` or `send_response()`

Comment: @Yaroslav the py-cord documentation has [`ctx.reply`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=reply#discord.ext.commands.Context.reply) as well, are you not able to use this?